# Expressing $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}}$ with rational Denominator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions, radicals

could you please help me express this with a rational denominator

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}}$

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

First, multiply the expression with $$\frac{(\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3) - \sqrt 5}{(\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3) - \sqrt 5}$$

What do you get as a result? Is the way forward clear to you? If not, post the result and we can see what to do in the next step.

Comment: $= \frac{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5}}{2+2\sqrt{6} + 3 - 5}$

Comment: @PlsHelpMe $2+3-5=0$

Comment: @PlsHelpMe Add a dollar mark at the end to make the thing readable. Also, simplify the denominator.

Comment: $= \frac{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{6}}$

Comment: @PlsHelpMe Do you know what to do next? You probably learned in school how to express $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ with a rational denominator?

Comment: then multiply by $ \frac{\sqrt{6}}{\sqrt{6}} $

Comment: @PlsHelpMe The minus is not necesary.

Comment: i can't get rid of it?

Comment: @PlsHelpMe Nor the $2$, since you only care to make the denominator rational so rational multiples don't matter.

Comment: @PlsHelpMe What do you mean "I can't get rid of it"?

Comment: sorry, $ = \frac{2\sqrt{3} + 3\sqrt{2} -\sqrt{30}}{12}$

Comment: @PlsHelpMe How did you get $2\sqrt 3$?

Answer (score 1):

We can use the conjugate trick for rationalizing denominators more than once:

$$\frac1{\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt5}\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt3-\sqrt5}{\sqrt2+\sqrt3-\sqrt5}\frac{\sqrt6}{\sqrt6}=\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt3-\sqrt5}{2\sqrt6}\frac{\sqrt6}{\sqrt6}=\frac{2\sqrt3+3\sqrt2-\sqrt{30}}{12}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}}\frac{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}}=$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt6}=\frac{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt6}\frac{\sqrt6}{\sqrt6}=\frac{\sqrt{12}+\sqrt{18}-\sqrt{30}}{12}$$