# Rationalize the denominator with 4 terms $\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{12}-\sqrt[3]{3}-\sqrt[3]{9}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, fractions, rationalising-denominator

Rationalize the denominator of this fraction

$$\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{12}-\sqrt[3]{3}-\sqrt[3]{9}}$$

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Please let us know what you've tried so we can help you better!

Comment: Interesting. This question is somewhat similar to [question 1192230](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192230/expressing-frac1-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt5-with-rational-denominator), same level of detail. However, question 1192230 has been voted up while this question has been put on hold and voted down. Moderators, any second thoughts?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your expression "simplifies" to
$$
{-3\cdot3^{1/6} + 3^{1/3} + 7 \sqrt{3} + 5\cdot3^{2/3} + 2\cdot3^{5/6} - 2\over 22}
$$
**Outline of solution:** First, transform the given expression to this convenient form:
$$
{1\over(1-3^{1/3}+3^{1/6})(1+3^{1/3}-3^{1/6})},
$$
then multiply both the numerator and denominator by $(3^{1/3}+3^{1/6}+1)(3^{1/3}+3^{1/6}-1)$ so that the denominator looks more symmetric, like Heron's formula: 
$$(3^{1/3}+3^{1/6}+1)(3^{1/3}+3^{1/6}-1)(1-3^{1/3}+3^{1/6})(1+3^{1/3}-3^{1/6})
$$
Simplify the denominator (let $x=3^{1/6}$):
$$(x^2+x+1)(x^2+x-1)(1-x^2+x)(1+x^2-x) 
= 2x^6-1-(x^6-2)x^2+x^4 
$$
$$= 5-3^{1/3}+3^{2/3} \quad\mbox{(here we used: }\ 
   2x^6-1=5, \ \ (x^6-2)x^2=3^{1/3}).
$$
So the denominator becomes $5-3^{1/3}+3^{2/3}$. Finally, use the fact that
$$
(5 - 3^{1/3} + 3^{2/3})\times(7 + 2\cdot3^{1/3} - 3^{2/3}) = 44.
$$
*Note:* This is a special case ($n=3$, $x=3^{1/6}$) of the following: 
for $x=n^{1/6}$, $n\in{\mathbb N}$, the product
$$
((2n-1)-(n-2)x^2+x^4) \ \times \ ((5n-1)+(2n-2)x^2+(n-5)x^4)
$$
$$
= -(n - 1) (n^2 - 18 n + 1)
$$
is an integer.

Comment: And your original reply to my warning was ** I want to see how many and how quickly downvotes come**, Atleast now you know how quickly they come. Anyways Happy New Year $\displaystyle \huge \ddot \smile$.

Comment: Happy New Year everyone! If you have an alternative solution, please work on getting this question reopened. (btw "This should be a comment" now makes no sense at all.)

Comment: This question can't be reopened because the op did not provide his work. And even if he provides it now it is unlikely that this question will reopen.